# I found Fatal Error in Stripe Integration

Tags: php, laravel-5, stripe-payments

Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_0uWOhuErSVVYrT) Must provide source or customer. thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\augermates\stripe\vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\Exception\ApiErrorException.php on line 38

```
<?php 
include('config.php');

$price=500;
$name="augermates";

$token=$_POST['stripeToken'];

$data=\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount"=> 500,
  "currency"=> "USD",
  "Description"=> "augermates",
  "Source"=>$token,


));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($token);


 ?>
```

Comment: i am pretty sure it is case sensitive so you should use `source` instead of `Source`

Comment: Thank you So Much. I lost my last 1 hours to search the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to set you API key and don't use Capitalized index names.
Try this code:

```
include('config.php');

$price = 500;
$name = "augermates";

// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('YOUR-API-KEY-HERE');

// Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  'amount' => $price*100,
  'currency' => 'USD',
  'source' => $token,
  "description"=> "augermates",
  'statement_descriptor' => 'Custom descriptor',
]);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($charge);
```